# Issues with Django Import-Export: Validation Errors during CSV Import

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-import-export

I am currently working on a Django project where I'm using the django-import-export library to import CSV data into my models through the Django admin interface. I have set up resources, models, and made necessary changes in the admin, but I'm facing validation errors during the import process.

I have the following structure in my Django project:

models.py: Contains the definitions of various models like PlayStyles, Coaches, Stadiums, Leagues, Teams, Players, Matches, and Statistics.

resources.py: Includes corresponding ModelResource classes for each model.

admin.py: Configures the Django admin interface to use the ModelResource classes for data import/export.

CSV Files: I have CSV files for each model with data to be imported.

Despite setting up the resources correctly, I am encountering issues when importing CSV files for certain models, specifically for Teams. The error message mentions validation errors related to foreign key fields (stadium, coach, and league).

Here's a snippet of my relevant code:
models.py:

```
# ... (models for PlayStyles, Coaches, Stadiums, Leagues, etc.)
class Teams(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    established_year = models.IntegerField()
    stadium = models.ForeignKey(Stadiums, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Coaches, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    league = models.ForeignKey(Leagues, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_of_titles = models.IntegerField()
```

resources.py:

```
# ... (resources for PlayStyles, Coaches, Stadiums, Leagues, etc.)
class TeamsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Teams
        fields = ('name', 'established_year', 'stadium', 'coach', 'league', 'number_of_titles')
```

admin.py:

```
# ... (admin configurations for PlayStyles, Coaches, Stadiums, Leagues, etc.)
class TeamsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'established_year', 'stadium', 'coach', 'league', 'number_of_titles')
    resource_class = TeamsResource

admin.site.register(Teams, TeamsAdmin)
```

csv file teams.csv:

```
name,established_year,stadium,coach,league,number_of_titles
TeamA,1990,Old Trafford,Jurgen Klopp,Premier League,5
TeamB,1985,Camp Nou,Pep Guardiola,La Liga,3
```

I suspect that the issue is related to how I'm handling foreign key fields during the import. Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: most probably, the issue is related to the foreign keys. it is important to have their primary keys instead of their names within your csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any field as a ForeignKey reference in your import.  It doesn't have to be a primary key, however you must declare `ForeignKeyWidget` correctly.

For example:

```py
# Am guessing your model structure here - adapt accordingly
# You will have to add other ForeignKeyWidget declarations 
# for your other relations
class TeamsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    stadium = fields.Field(
        column_name='stadium',
        attribute='name',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Stadiums, field='name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('stadium',)
```

This will allow you to import a Team object and link it to the correct Stadium instance based on the stadium name in your import file.

The stadium instance has to exist already, and has to be uniquely identifiable by name.  You can configure django-import-export to create FK relations if they don't exist.  Please refer to the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#importing-model-relations).

You will obviously need to adapt your implementation based on the example above.